# DOMPDF class not found

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I need to convert HTML to PDF with bootstrap, i have got a code from online its working fine but when i add same code to my project its showing below error

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in XXXXXXX**

Below is my Code

```
       $template = "HTML CODE"

        require_once("vendor/autoload.php");            

        use Dompdf\Dompdf;
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $dompdf->loadHtml($template);
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
        $dompdf->render();

        file_put_contents("pdfs/invoice-" . mt_rand(0,99999) . ".pdf",  $dompdf->output());
        $dompdf->stream("invoice");
```

I dont know why this error is coming

Comment: Is this the extent of your code? The `use` statement should be in the global scope (i.e. not inside a function declaration). Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: its not a function...

Comment: Unrelated until you resolve your syntax error, but you shouldn't use both the `output` and `stream` methods or your PDF will likely experience corruption.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon in the first line ... though I'm guessing that's just a typo in the sample and not present in your actual code.